# How to scrape some information (for example author name and url ) from given data

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

Below is piece of data that is stored in one of my python variable name data.

```
<script data-rh="true" type="application/ld+json"> {"@context":"http:\u002F\u002Fschema.org","@type":"NewsArticle","image":["https:\u002F\u002Fmiro.medium.com\u002Fmax\u002F1200\u002F1*CyeMUlN5qml62Kl5YfujUA.png"],"url":"https:\u002F\u002Fmedium.com\u002Fjob-advice-for-software-engineers\u002Fwhat-i-want-and-dont-want-to-see-on-your-software-engineering-resume-cbc07913f7f6","dateCreated":"2019-01-01T01:51:11.291Z","datePublished":"2019-01-01T01:51:11.291Z","dateModified":"2021-04-02T18:23:51.905Z","headline":"What I want (and don’t want) to see on your software engineering resume","name":"What I want (and don’t want) to see on your software engineering resume","description":"Asking what should be on a resume is one of the most common questions I hear. I’ve seen thousands of resumes, interviewed hundreds, and hired or helped hire dozens, so I’ll describe exactly what I’m…","identifier":"cbc07913f7f6","author":{"@type":"Person","name":"James S. Fisher","url":"https:\u002F\u002Fmedium.com\u002F@jamessfisher"},"creator":["James S. Fisher"],"publisher":{"@type":"Organization","name":"Job Advice for Software Engineers","url":"https:\u002F\u002Fmedium.com\u002Fjob-advice-for-software-engineers","logo":{"@type":"ImageObject","width":308,"height":60,"url":"https:\u002F\u002Fmiro.medium.com\u002Fmax\u002F616\u002F1*OMF3fSqH8t4xBJ9-6oZDZw.png"}},"mainEntityOfPage":"https:\u002F\u002Fmedium.com\u002Fjob-advice-for-software-engineers\u002Fwhat-i-want-and-dont-want-to-see-on-your-software-engineering-resume-cbc07913f7f6","isAccessibleForFree":"False","hasPart":{"@type":"WebPageElement","isAccessibleForFree":"False","cssSelector":".meteredContent"}}</script>
```

without using jason, i just simply want to extract author and author url from this piece of data by using simple python.

Comment: Any specific reason to not use ```JSON``` ?

Answer (score 0):

As I was looking at your sample, I noticed that the content part of it is JSON. You can consider converting it to a python dictionary as JSON files are mostly compatible with this data type. Then you can use dictionary keys to extract your information.
Just use the following code:

```py
## Suppose you stored your data in a myData
dictionary_data = eval(di[51:-10])
print(dictionary_data['author']['name'])
print(dictionary_data['author']['url'])
```

On the other hand, if you want to do it without using a dictionary, you can use **regex** to pars your string and find what you want based on that. To put it simply, regex is a sort of pattern in a string that you can use in combination with various functions to extract a specific part of a string that follows the pattern.

For example, consider a string full of gibberish that in between the random characters an email address is hidden. You create a regex pattern, basically saying *look for some characters before an **@** which follows by some other characters, a dot, and two or more characters*.
You can use the same method to extract your information from the string.

Comment: what is in eval() function. can i pass my variable that store json data.

Comment: dictionary_data = eval(myData)

Comment: First __I Would Not Recommend Using This Function Unless You Are Absolutely Sure About What You Are Doing__. In large-scale applications, this function may cause some serious security issues. This function, basically _runs_ everything in its string argument as a python script. Explaining more is behind the scope of this question. Take a look at [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_eval.asp) for more info.

Comment: i can try regex pattern also. what will be the regex_pattern for author name and url

Comment: You can find a good tutorial for regex [here](https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285)